# can i start service from an other package in android

Tags: android

i want to do is that if my application is closed from the task manager  my service won't stop and if stops another package that is also running and checking the application process will turn my service ON how can i do it

Comment: does it mean that ultimately you want your service to keep running at any cost?

Comment: yes you can say that but i know android won't allow it so that why i am calling it from other package

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make sure that your service should keep running or should get recreated again after killed then you should return start_sticky from your onStartCommand() method which will make sure to recreate your service as soon as memory is free. check the following link for more detail. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY

Comment: i have used it but the issue is that if the application is closed from task manager an other package which is continuously checking the process will turn the service Start if it finds closed

Comment: yes you can start the service from another application but in that case you need to set package of targeting application while creating intent. Register both of your application under same certificate and use share user id option in manifest file. It will help you to tell OS that both application are from same user and OS will allow you to start service of one application from another application.